# Catch an error in piped MySQL command (bash)

Tags: mysql, bash

Is there any way to avoid the first `eval` for code below? I tried to play with `${LASTPIPE[0]}` and such things but it was way too complicated for me. For instance when I tried to inject code with semicolon (`$MYSQLCOMMAND; if ...`) it broke my output to the pipe. I spent more than 8 hours wandering StackOverflow just to give up and write one more SQL command without pipe. Don't want to publish bad written code.

```
MYSQLQUERY="select * from $TABLENAME"
MYSQLTOPTIONS="--defaults-extra-file=$EXTRA -h $HOSTNAME -D $DBNAME -N -e"
MYSQLCOMMAND='mysql $MYSQLTOPTIONS "$MYSQLQUERY"'

# Exit immediately if something wrong with MySQL command

if eval "$MYSQLCOMMAND > /dev/null" ; then : ; else \
printf "Script returned non-zero exit code: %s\n" "$?" ; exit $?; fi

# Count rows for valid JSON output

ROWS=0

eval $MYSQLCOMMAND | \
while read ; \
do  
    ((ROWS++))  
done

(rest of the code generates JSON with calling the same 
eval ... while read... and verified by https://jsonlint.com/)
```

Also I'd like to hear any your comment on the code since I'm not an experienced bash coder.

Comment: Maybe you should start by explaining exactly what you're trying to do - there are multiple issues with this script

Comment: The rest of the script generates JSON. What issues are you talking about? I tested output JSON and it's valid.

Comment: Run it through https://www.shellcheck.net and it will highlight some of them. You still haven't explained what you're trying to do. Do you want to check the sql command works? Check something in the response? Why do you need `eval`? Why are you reading `name` and `status` into the while loop?

Comment: Thanks for giving advice about shellcheck.net. I edited code.
The rest of the script works perfectly, I just want to prevent script from executing other lines if there is an error.